# How to fix concrete delamination

Tags: concrete, cement

When I made some concrete flooring (my first time doing it) I finished the surface while there was still bleed water (I didn't know it better back then). Now 2 months later in a few areas there is delamination problems on the surface, it is mostly thin areas of a few milimeters.

Now, after I remove all of this, how can I fix it and make it bond properly (since it is only a few milimeters deep). I thought about making a slurry of cement and fine sand (1:1) with bonding additive, but I'm not sure if it is the best course of action.

Oh, I'm in Brazil, and here we don't carrry a huge selection of toppings, overlays, self-leveling compounds and such. The ones that we do have are expensive as hell, so I'm reduced to making my own with with basic components: cement, sand, thinset (rigid and flexible), a few concrete additives (for bonding, expanding, etc), etc.